# How to subquery "Default Opportunity Team" when querying for User?

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, user

Cannot figure out the relationship name for **Default Opportunity Team** on **User**.

```
List<User> users = 
    [select id, name,

    // default opportunity team       
    (select id, TeamMemberRole, user.name from .....)

    from User 
    limit 100];
```

I thought that it might be `UserTeams`, but that's the relationship name of UserTeamMember's **userid** field.

I need the relationship name of UserTeamMember's **ownerid** field.

If you post the answer, please advise how you found it.

Comment: Just as a note - UserTeams related list shows where this particular user is a member of somebody else's "Default Account Team".   It is not showing THIS user's "Default Opportunity Team" or "Default Account Team".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This relationship is not queriable.**

Below is the query to get all of the relationship names for the **User** object:

```
select ParentSobjectId, ChildSobjectId, RelationshipName 
from RelationshipDomain 
where ParentSobjectId = 'User' 
and RelationshipName != null
```

There are a few "...Team"-type relationships, but none of them are the **Default Opportunity Team**.  Instead, they are teams on Account, Opportunity, and User objects, where this User is a member.

**AccountTeams** - queries **AccountTeamMember** object

**OpportunityTeams** - queries **OpportunityTeamMember** object

**UserTeams** - queries **UserTeamMember** object

Comment: Here is the query to get Default Opportunity Team:  SELECT Id, UserId, User.Name, TeamMemberRole FROM UserTeamMember where ownerid = 'SOME_USER_ID'